# Wrong 'View live' url in Wagtail admin message after page creation when using id as slug

Tags: wagtail

I am using a page model 'EventPage', which shall have a slug based on the id of the page. To achieve this, I have modified the `full_clean` method like this (similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43662817/modify-slug-for-every-page-of-model-on-wagtail)):

```
class EventPage(Page):
    ...
    
    def full_clean(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().full_clean(*args, **kwargs)

        # set slug to id, if already existing
        if self.id is not None:
            self.slug = str(self.id)
```

This seems to work fine in principle. However, after the page is published,the Wagtail admin/pages view shows a message box at the top ('Page ... created and published') with a `View live` button that links to the wrong url (i.e. using the default slug created from the page title).

In the list of pages below that, the just created page's own `View live` and `Add child page` links show the correct page url using the page id. It is just the message box's `View live` url at the top that needs to be corrected. Here's a screenshot:

[image]

How can I get the correct link in the message box at the top as well?

In case it matters, I am currently using Wagtail 2.9, Django 2.2.9 and Python 3.6.
I guess my problem has something to do with the fact that the page id is not known until the page is saved for the first time, and the `View live` link in the message box somehow uses an initial page.url which is overridden later on.
Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone ending up here, the solution was given in the accepted answer to a similar question here: [Wagtail 'View live' button provides wrong url after page creation while using id as slug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70515946/wagtail-view-live-button-provides-wrong-url-after-page-creation-while-using-id).

In short: use Django signals instead of hooks, i.e. here a the `post_save` signal for EventPage.
For documentation purposes, I'm repeating here the solution from the linked question, slightly adjusted. All credits and thanks go to [gasman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1853523/gasman).

Create following signal in the calendar app, `calendar/signals.py`:

```py
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

from .models import EventPage

@receiver(post_save)
def set_number_and_slug_after_event_page_created(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if issubclass(sender, EventPage) and created:
        page = instance
        page.number = page.slug = str(page.id)
        page.save()
        new_revision = page.save_revision()
        if page.live:
            new_revision.publish()
```

And, if not yet done, register signals in the corresponding `calendar/apps.py` config:

```py
from django.apps import AppConfig

class CalendarConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'calendar'

    def ready(self):
        from . import signals
```

This worked like a charm for me.

Answer (score 1):

You could probably achieve this by using Hooks in Wagtail. Hooks are typically used to customize the view-level behaviour of the Wagtail admin and front end. I would suggest overwriting the button functionality this way, or possibly removing the existing button and adding your own new one in. More info in the docs: https://docs.wagtail.io/en/latest/reference/hooks.html

Comment: Thanks, good idea! I had hoped to fix it without hooks, but I'll give it a try.

Comment: I had tried it with the Wagtail hooks, but couldn't get it to work with e.g.  'after_publish_page', because I couldn't get the correct live url.
It seems one needs to use Django signals instead, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70515946/ and the accepted answer, which also solved the issue for me.